# jQuery Div rotate?

Tags: jquery, html, rotation

Is it possible to rotate a div (static)? I have search on Google and found "jqueryrotate" but this will not working in IE 8 and IE 7.

Does somebody know a solution?

Comment: As far as i know, it is only possible with HTML5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely use css3 rotates for all standard-conform browsers and use **filters for IE**.

```
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE9 */
       -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */ 
          transform: rotate(7.5deg);
             filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */ 
                     M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157,M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104, sizingMethod='auto expand');
               zoom: 1;
```

a handy website to help you with this: [css3please](http://css3please.com/)

Comment: This is a solution for none-IE. It is not possible in all browsers that can't use HTML5 and CSS3 (or got own methods to do that).

Comment: @TaiKahar "This is a solution for none-IE.": wrong! read again please.

Comment: @TaiKahar the `filter`-rule should be in a separate conditional stylesheet for IE of course.

Answer (score 0):

In you jqueryrotate.js file replace this:

line ~132
 `this._img.parentNode.removeChild(this._img);`//replace this...
 `jQuery(this._img).parent().find(this._img).remove();`// with this